# error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'const char*' line 23

Tags: c++

I was comparing two strings, but unfortunately this error occurred

> error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'const char*' line 23

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class car {

    public:
    int feulcp, batterycp, length, height, width, seater, torque, power, temp;
    char ownername[20], noplate[12], statecheck[20];

    string statename[28] = {"andhra pradesh", "arunachal pradesh", "assam,bihar", "chhattisgarh", "goa", "gujarat", "haryana", "himachal pradesh", "jharkhand", "karnataka", "kerala", "madhya pradesh", "maharashtra", "manipur", "meghalaya", "mizoram", "nagaland", "odisha", "punjab", "rajasthan", "sikkim", "tamil nadu", "telangana", "tripura", "uttarakhand", "uttar pradesh", "west bengal"};

    car() {
        cout << "Please Enter Your State Name: ";
        y:
        cin >> statecheck;
        for(int i=0; i<=27; i++) {
            temp = strcmp(statename[i], statecheck); // Here is the error!!!
            if(temp == 0) {
                goto x;
            }
            else
                cout << "INVALID STATE NAME \n PLEASE RE-ENTER ";
            goto y;
        }
        x:
            cout << "successful";
    }

};

int main() {
    car car1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use the `c_str()` member function of `std::string` to get a `char*` that is usable by `strcmp`. But there are other issues in your code (probably typos) - please try to tidy up your post.

Comment: okay, I have just edited.

Comment: OK, apart from the fact that there is *seldom* a reason to use `goto` statements in C++, ask yourself what happens if the entered state text does not match the *very first* in the list. How will your code ever test it against the second in the list? Or the third?

Comment: Also, until such time as you `#include <string>`, there is no `std::string` formally dictated. If you're using the `std::string` class, [you *must* include `<string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) . There are no exceptions, and if it *appears* to work, that just means you rolled the dice and you auto tires didn't flatten.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp()` takes `const char*` parameters, but you are passing it a `std::string` object instead, hence the error. Use the [`std::string::c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method to get a `const char*`:

```cpp
temp = strcmp(statename[i].c_str(), statecheck);
```

That being said, there is no need to use `strcmp()` at all, as `std::string` has its own `operator==` and `compare()` methods for performing string comparisons, eg:

```cpp
if (statename[i] == statecheck){
```

```cpp
if (statename[i].compare(statecheck) == 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Synopsis: strcmp()

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

Both arguments for strcmp() should be interpreted as type unsigned char, and their difference is calculated.

```
temp=strcmp(statename[i],statecheck);
```

In your code, "statename" is "std::string" and the compiler fails the implicit conversion from  std::string to const char*.

#### Solution

```
temp = strcmp(statename[i].c_str(), statecheck);
```

*std::string::c_str*: will represent the current value of the string in C-string.

#### Note

Replacing:

`char statecheck[20];` with `std::string statecheck;`
`temp=strcmp(statename[i].c_str(),statecheck);` and `if(temp==0)` with `if(statename[i] == statecheck)`

will be better and, as [Adrian Mole explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68965516/error-cannot-convert-std-cxx11string-aka-std-cxx11basic-stringch#comment121883559_68965516), the code will fail to provide the expected result.